# Using same port for web-hosting and geth node

Tags: web3js, django

I'm hosting a Django website on an Apache virtual machine and wanted to connect it Ethereum. Currently, the page I'm working on is hosted at

`146.169.45.149:9002`

Since I wanted to run a node at that address so I could connect the two, I ran this to start geth

`geth --genesis customGenesis.json --rpc --rpcaddr "146.169.45.149" --rpcport "9002" --datadir testchain --nodiscover --networkid 1234 console`

However, this isn't working and I'm getting the following error

`Fatal: Error starting RPC: listen tcp 146.169.45.149:9002: bind: address already in use`

Everything else seems to be working but the code is this

```
<!------- SCRIPT------------------>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Web3 = require('web3');
    var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("146.169.45.149:9002"));
    var mining = web3.eth.mining;
    document.getElementById("Mining").innerText = mining;
</script>

</body>
```

I'm new at this so it could be something related to rpc but I couldn't figure it out from what I read.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to make it work by running
`geth --genesis customGenesis.json --rpc --rpcport "9012" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir testchain --networkid 1234 console`

From what I understood, this works but it's less secure. I would like to find a safer way of doing it.

Also, I had to change something in the script part which is now

```
<!------- SCRIPT------------------>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var Web3 = require('web3');

  var web3 = new Web3();

    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://146.169.45.149:9012"));
    var mining = web3.eth.mining;
    document.getElementById("Mining").innerText = web3.eth.accounts[0];
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run more than one program to listen and serve on a single port on the same computer:

If you want to serve your Apache web page on the port `9002`, choose another port for `geth` to serve it's RPC requests on.

For example, use port `9001` for `geth` RPC:

```
geth --genesis customGenesis.json                   \
  --rpc --rpcaddr "146.169.45.149" --rpcport "9001" \
  --datadir testchain --nodiscover --networkid 1234 console
```

And in your script, use:

```
<!------- SCRIPT------------------>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Web3 = require('web3');
    var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("146.169.45.149:9001"));
    var mining = web3.eth.mining;
    document.getElementById("Mining").innerText = mining;
</script>
```

Comment: I tried doing that (changing the port on both the geth command and the setProvider statement) but it didn't work. I get a warning  
"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/" 

and an error 

`POST 
XHR 
http://146.169.45.149:9002/your_council/146.169.45.149:9012 [HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 29ms`

Comment: You probably need to set --rpccorsdomain

Comment: I tried with with  
`geth --genesis customGenesis.json --rpc --rpcaddr "146.169.45.149" --rpcport "9012" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir testchain --networkid 1234 console`  
but it still doesn't work.  
The error is  
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load %3146.169.45.149:9012. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource" and  "Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node 146.169.45.149:9012"